# Ocaml : Function with 'a option error

Tags: ocaml

I have this simple function which drives me crazy:

it should be a function of this type :

```
myfunction : (int * int list) list -> int -> int
```

For each tuples of the first argument :

When the second argument  matches the first element of the tuple then the function return the last element of the list in the tuple.

If no matches it should return -1.

```
let rec myfunction  alist anum =
  let last_e l =
    let len = List.length l in
    List.nth l (len - 1) in
  match alist with
  | [] -> -1
  | (n , ln) :: q -> if n = anum then last_e ln
  else myfunction q anum
```

But my function does not work and I have this error message in utop:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a option                                                                                                                                                                           but an expression was expected of type int
```

I don't know where the "option" type comes from.

Comment: Are You sure You've isolated right function from Your code? Because calling e.g. `myfunction [(1, [1]); (2, [2])] 2` gives me `2` (without error).

Comment: @barti_ddu, it seems normal because I tested this in utop with the Core loaded. see the answer that I accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you are using some OCaml toplevel (e.g. `utop`) and you have these lines in your `.ocamlinit` file

```
#require "core.top" ;;
open Core.Std ;;
```

This enables the Core libraries, where `List.nth` has type:

```
μ> List.nth;;
- : 'a list -> int -> 'a option = <fun>
```

instead of standard OCaml's `List.nth : 'a list -> int -> 'a`.

So, when you fire up your toplevel and say:

```
μ> #use "myfunction.ml";;
```

you get the same error you cited in the question.

By the way, if you'd like to keep using Core, there is a `List.last` function.